# Ruby: FormatMessageW trouble

Tags: ruby, winapi

What's a correct way to call FormatMessageW in Ruby?

```
   require 'win32api'

   FormatMessage = Win32API.new 'kernel32', 'FormatMessageW', 'IPIIPII', 'I'
   msg = '\0' * 255
   FormatMessage.call 0x00001000 | 0x00000100, nil, 6, 1024, msg, 0, 0
```

FormatMessage returns not null result but msg contains not readable message. What's wrong?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem, but without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) it is unnecessarily hard to help you.  All you would need to do is remove the ellipsis, show us the code for printing `msg`, and say the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: Hmm... What are the ellipsis you talk about? msg output is like: "Шщ$ \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0..."

Comment: What @DavidGrayson is asking for is a [mcve]. This code is only part of how you're trying to call `FormatMessage`.  There's nothing here to show any checking of the return value from the function call, or how the `msg` parameter is being used after the call. `msg` is allocated, but then the call to  `FormatMessage` specifies that it should allocate a buffer itself.  There are a lot of questions here that could be answered with a [mcve].

Comment: That's all code. Or I should write something else?

Comment: "That's all code. Or I should write something else?" Please read the links provided in the comments. It's important we be able to test the code, not just see a snippet.

Comment: kate, your program currently has no lines that print anything.  So the expected output is empty, and I would guess that the actual output is also empty, which means the program is working fine.  Can't you just add a line with `p msg` or `puts msg` or whatever you are doing to actually generate output?  Or just tell us that you ran it in IRB, which automatically inspects and prints the result from every line.  That way, other developers can see the same thing you are seeing.  (Also, be sure to test the small program yourself and make sure it still exhibits the bad behavior.)

Comment: Face palm... I already told what puts msg returns random symbols and nothing else. What I should to write to stop your not useful replies? If you can not help then I'll break the problem without your junk posts, antiguru.

Comment: You didn't say the word `puts` until your very last comment.   If you want free expert advice on how to fix the contents of a string, you should be more eager to say how exactly how you are looking at the string when someone asks.  The point is that there are different ways to look at a string and you shouldn't expect people to guess what you are doing.  Now that you have told us you are using `puts`, it would be possible for an answerer to construct an SSCCE from the information given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the code you are looking for:

```
require 'win32api'

FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x1000
FormatMessage = Win32API.new 'kernel32', 'FormatMessageW', 'IPIIPIP', 'I'
msgw = ("\x00" * 256).force_encoding("UTF-16LE")
count = FormatMessage.call FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, nil, 6, 1033, msgw, msgw.size, nil
msgw = msgw[0, count]
msg = msgw.encode("UTF-8")
puts msg
```

When I run this with Ruby, the output is "The handle is invalid.", which is the correct Windows error message for error code 6.

There were some problems with your original code.

1. The last argument to [FormatMessageW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) is a pointer, so you should use `P` instead of `I`, especially if you want it to work on 64-bit Windows.
2. In Ruby `'\0'` is actually a two-byte ASCII string, not a single-byte null character.  You can confirm this by running `p '\0'.bytes.to_a`.  It looks like you tried to allocate 255 bytes, but you actually allocated 510 bytes.  You should allocate an even number of bytes because wide characters in Windows take 2 bytes.
3. As @theB pointed out, your first argument to `FormatMessageW` was wrong, since you specified that `FormatMessageW` should allocate its own buffer.
4. You specified language code 1024.  I can't find a definition for that.  Maybe you meant 1033, which is "English - United States".  Specifying 1024 doesn't seem to actually cause problems though.
5. You should use `force_encoding` to set the encoding of your string to UTF-16LE, because that is the encoding used for wide strings in Windows (or if it's not exactly the same, at least it is compatible most of the time).
6. The 6th argument to FormatMessageW should be the number of characters in your buffer (which is the number of bytes divided by 2, by the way).  Your code just passed 0 for that argument.
7. Strings in Ruby can contain any arbitrary bytes, including null characters, but it's not necessarily a good idea to let that happen because things like `String#size` will return surprising results.  `FormatMessageW` returns the number of characters in the formatted message, so we can use that to trim off the null characters at the end.  (Conveniently, `FormatMessageW` returns 0 if there is an error, so our trimming would result in an empty string.)
8. You should use `String#encode` to convert your string from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 because UTF-8 strings are much easier to operate on and print in Ruby.

If you don't care about internationalization and unicode, you could have just used `FormatMessageA` instead.  Here is some code that will work for that:

```
require 'win32api'

FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x1000
FormatMessage = Win32API.new 'kernel32', 'FormatMessageA', 'IPIIPIP', 'I'
msg = ("\x00" * 256).force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")
count = FormatMessage.call FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, nil, 6, 1033, msg, msg.size, nil
msg = msg[0, count]
puts msg
```

P.S. DWORD is an unsigned integer type.  I am not sure what the right letter for that is in Ruby's Win32API class; it might be that `I` represents a signed integer, and should be replaced by something else.

Comment: I take my words back. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, what about LocalFree?

Comment: There is no need to call LocalFree because we are not using FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER.  Our buffer is simply a Ruby string, and its memory is managed by Ruby.

Comment: In other words GC of Ruby will collect msg automatically when it'll be unuseful, right? Thank you again!

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep, it will be garbage collected.